# Home network - cant access other computer

Tags: networking, workgroup

I have 2 computers (HUMMER1, HUMMER2) connected to a Gygabyte switch, which is connected to my router.
Both computers had "WORKGROUP" as workgroup name.
Under Network, HUMMER 1 could see HUMMER 2, the router and a network printer. HUMMER 2 could only see the router.
I then changed the workgroup for both pcs to "HOMEGROUP", rebooted, and now the situation has reversed! HUMMER 2 sees the whole network, HUMMER 1 only sees the router.
All advice is appreciated. Both PCs running Windows 10 Pro.

Answer (score 1):

Are both machines numbered the same? in other words, do both get their IP addresses from the router using DHCP? And when you say "see each other", how exactly are you looking?

Try this: Go to RUN and type in `\\IP address`,
that is, the IP address of the other machine, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
If the other machine it is sharing a folder then you should be able to see it.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot about the text tool they use here so I didn't escape the characters. in quotes that should be two backslashes followed by the IP address of the other machine.

Comment: Put three backslashes in your edit. Not sure why the double doesn't show up.

Comment: Thanks. Here is what I know: HUMMER2 has IPV4 address of 192.168.1.104/24. HUMMER 1 has IPV4 address of 192.168.1.100/24. In "NETWORK and INTERNET > STATE" only HUMMER2 has an option to create a Domestic Group. When opening an Explorer window, if I click on NETWORK on the left sidebar, HUMMER 2 can see HUMMER 1 (if I click it, it goes to the shared folders) but, doing the same in HUMMER 1, he cant see HUMMER 2 (as a computer on the network). However, it can open the shared folders by using the RUN command and typing the IP of HUMMER 2. So shares are working, but discovery of devices isnt?

Comment: @BMM is network discovery turned on in both PC's? Type network in the search box and choose Network and Sharing Center in the list to open it. -> Select Change advanced sharing settings. -> Check both to make sure it's turned on. File sharing obviously is if you can reach the network share via IP. Let us know the outcome.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart thanks; I've checked, Network Discovery is on on both machines. Strange is that this behaviour switches. It switched again. Now it's HUMMER1 that can see 2, and 2 cant see 1 (i.e. appear as a PC in Network). Maybe something with my hardware? I have a my main broadband router, connected to a technicolor router (both were supplied by my internet provider, instead of just one equipment) and the last on is connected to a gigabyte switch I've purchased. Both HUMMER1 and 2 and connected to this switch through an ethernet cable. Thanks for helping

Comment: Weird, firewall/antivirus is off for troubleshooting right? I'm taking shots in the dark here, tried updating the nic drivers?

Comment: Here's what I'd do: Give both machines a static address outside the range of DHCP, this way they can always be found at the same address. Enter this info into the host file on both machines, this will give you a way to reach them with DNS, Then, if I understand you correctly, you said that running the two backslashes followed by the ip address worked on both machines. So I would create a shortcut on both desktops that has the two backslashes followed by the other machine name(or ip address) and use them to access the shares on the other machine. Should work with Firewall and Anti-virus up.